# SQLmap on Login. Expect 401 reponse

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

I'm using sqlmap to test a login. When using invalid credentials, the webserver sends back a 401 response. However, sqlmap interprets this response as I'm not authorized to call this page and needs credentials (as in `--auth-type`)
How do I tell sqlmap, the 401 is a valid response, when the username is wrong?

Here an example:

```
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: close

{"username":"user*","password":"pass*"}
```

Assuming user/pass are valid login credentials, the server responses with 200. As soon as a Injection is added to username or password, the server responds with 401.

I want SQLmap to ignore 401 responses and try other injections. I already tried `--ignore-code=401` which results in `[CRITICAL] unable to retrieve page content`